# Setting Windows PowerShell environment variables

Tags: windows, powershell

I have found out that setting the PATH environment variable affects only the old command prompt. PowerShell seems to have different environment settings. How do I change the environment variables for PowerShell (v1)?

Note:

I want to make my changes permanent, so I don't have to set it every time I run PowerShell. Does PowerShell have a profile file? Something like Bash profile on Unix?

Comment: I'd like to have a central profile located on a file share. Synchronization is a pain. Creating a stub profile with . \\computer\share\path\Profile.ps1 seems like a kludge (try Notepad $Profile). It would be nice if there was a way to permanently change the $Profile automatic variable.

Comment: No the PATH environment *does* affect powershell command prompt as well. What differs though is that powershell does not accept paths enclosed in quotes. Solution: remove all enclosing quotes (`"`) in the path environment variable

Comment: IF YOU LAND HERE FOR PS > v1... Further to Nilzor's comment above: Use this to remove all " from paths in the PATH environment variable for your session: `$($Env:PATH).Split(';') | %{ $str += "$($_.Trim('"'));" }; $Env:PATH=$str`

Comment: With respect to _non-PowerShell-specific_ persistent updates, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69236623/45375. Note that **solutions based on  `setx.exe` and `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()` should be _avoided_**, because they invariably replace `REG_EXPAND_SZ` definitions with `REG_SZ` entries, meaning that entries that _dynamically_ reference _other_ environment variables are converted to _static_ entries. Additionally, `setx.exe` has a hard length limit of 1024 characters.

Comment: the PowerShell cmdlet `Add-Path` can be used if following @mklement0 recommendation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding path permanently to windows using powershell doesn't appear to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69236623/adding-path-permanently-to-windows-using-powershell-doesnt-appear-to-work)

Comment: Please consider changing the preferred answer to this question.

Answer (score 798, accepted):

Changing the actual environment variables can be done by
using the `env: namespace / drive` information. For example, this
code will update the path environment variable:

```
$env:PATH = "SomeRandomPath";             (replaces existing path) 
$env:PATH += ";SomeRandomPath"            (appends to existing path)
```

### Making change permanent

There are ways to make environment settings permanent, but
if you are only using them from PowerShell, it's probably
a lot better to use [Powershell *profiles*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles) script.

Everytime a new instance of Powershell starts, it look for specific script files (named *profile* files) and execute them if they do exist. You can edit one of these profile to customize your enviroment.

To know where those *profile* scripts are located in your computer type:

```
$profile                                     
$profile.AllUsersAllHosts           
$profile.AllUsersCurrentHost        
$profile.CurrentUserAllHosts    
$profile.CurrentUserCurrentHost
```

You can edit one of them, for example, by typing:

```
notepad $profile
```

Comment: $profile is an automatic variable that points at your user profile for all PowerShell hosts.

Comment: Note that (split-path $profile)(to get the containing folder) can contain multiple profile files: profile.ps1 should be loaded by all hosts, <host-name>_profile.ps1 just by the specified host. For PowerShell.exe (console host), this is Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1.

Comment: What if I don't have a folder WindowsPowerShell in my documents? Should I create the folder and the file? What should I put in the file if I want to add `C:\path\to\file.ext` to the environment variables? EDIT: found it already. Answer is yes, create it. The file should consist of 1 line: `$env:path += ;C:\path\to\file.ext"`.

Comment: @Lewistrick You don't have a profile by default. I followed these instructions to create one: http://www.howtogeek.com/50236/customizing-your-powershell-profile/

Comment: Be careful doing this -- it will clobber your existing path. 

```$env:Path = "SomeRandomPath";
 ```
Instead - see @mloskot, below.

Comment: `;` is essential to prepend to the value string as the delimiter to separate pathes

Comment: I've got a text file will all the variables needed for Visual Studio 2017 build tools to run, is this the proper way to add those variables in? the `PATH` variable has some stuff added on, would your solution wipe out everything originally in the `PATH` variable? I'd rather not have to edit the variables myself, but my batch file just won't open PS after initialising the environment.

Comment: Can I add individual Variables (like $timo='123') to the profile file or is it better do have a `.psd1` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54706752/1705829)?

Comment: I don't see why this is considered an answer. The question is how to permanently update the PATH, and this does not do that. This is *not* an answer to the question asked. "I want to make my changes permanent, so I don't have to set it every time I run PowerShell." is NOT answered. (I have added an answer that affects a permanent change on this thread).

Comment: @YorSubs The key requirement is  "so I don't have to set it every time", I think the client doesn't always know the best way to get what they want so I think we should look past the solution proposed by the client and give the best solution that meets their needs. (NB: client also proposed a "profile file")

Comment: I am getting "Running scripts is disabled on this system" when I restart PowerShell and it tries to run my profile script.

Comment: This is NOT making the change permanent.

Answer (score 852):

If, some time during a PowerShell session, you need to see or to *temporarily* modify the PATH environment variable , you can type one of these commands:

```
$env:Path                             # shows the actual content
$env:Path = 'C:\foo;' + $env:Path     # attach to the beginning
$env:Path += ';C:\foo'                # attach to the end
```

Comment: +1 :: This one-liner is quite effective for session-based invocations as with mingw ... I.E. $env:PATH += ";c:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin" ^ {some mingw bin ... }

Comment: and how do I remove a path?

Comment: @becko ask new SO question. This is specifically about *setting* env variable.

Comment: If you need  your path to be called before standard one, insert it at the beginning                  `$env:Path = "C:\MyPath;$env:Path"`

Comment: ****Don't forget the semicolon at the start of the appending string, as seen in @Kevin 's comment.  This is pretty obvious, but can be missed if you simply copy/paste the code in the answer and didn't have a semicolon at the end of the existing path.  I'll try to submit an edit.

Comment: @MattGoodrich I've rollback to previous revision

Comment: becko, to remove a path requires some code: $env:PATH = ($env:PATH -split ";" | %{ if($_ -ne "/path_to_remove") { $_ } }) -join ";"

Comment: If you modify the PATH env variable as part of an Admin Powershell instance, I believe this is a permanent change to the system-level PATH var (ie. not a temporary process-level change).

Answer (score 471):

You can also modify user/system environment variables **permanently** (i.e. will be persistent across shell restarts) with the following:

Modify a system environment variable

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable
     ("Path", $env:Path, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

Modify a user environment variable

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable
     ("INCLUDE", $env:INCLUDE, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
```

Usage from comments - add to the system environment variable

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(
    "Path",
    [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine) + ";C:\bin",
    [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

String based solution is also possible if you don't want to write types

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $env:Path + ";C:\bin", "Machine")
```

Comment: This is a very useful for restricted access systems.

Comment: @AndresRiofrio, Yes, this is permanent. 
Usage: `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $env:Path + ";C:\bin", [EnvironmentVariableTartget::Machine)` 
**You will not see the result of this change until you start a new powershell session.** That is, if you inspect $env:Path immediately after running this command, you will see what $env:Path was before the command. To update, close and open the shell or start a new session.

Comment: @FLGMwt you have a typo, correct is: [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $env:Path + ";C:\bin", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)

Comment: You can write the string "Machine" or "User" instead of the whole .NET enum. From [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730964.aspx).

Comment: @FLGMwt Is there any way to "refresh" the session to see said changes without closing/opening the shell?

Comment: @Erutan409 There's three targets possible for SetEnvironmentVariable.  `[EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine` which affects new processes for everybody permanently, `[EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User` which affects new processes for the current user permanently, and `[EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Process`, which affects the current process environment only.  You could set the variable twice, once for the User/Machine, and once for the Process.  That would affect the variable for new processes and the current process. Other current processes wouldn't be affected, however.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `setx`, but also this requires a shell restart. So @BaconBits has the best answer. Which should be added to the answer above.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I tried to add a directory to the User path variable, and everything seemed to work, but after starting a new Powershell terminal `$env::PATH` remained unchanged.

Comment: I would like you to be aware of the fact that this answer will ruin any dynamic (a.k.a expanded) items in your path. 

Eg. if you have

`GIT_INSTALL_ROOT=c:\tools\git` and `PATH=...;%GIT_INSTALL_ROOT%\cmd;%GIT_INSTALL_ROOT%\mingw64\bin` in your Environment  you will lose all references to `GIT_INSTALL_ROOT` variable in your Path, so it will become hardwired to some fixed directory

Comment: Again, this is NOT an answer to the question "I want to make my changes permanent, so I don't have to set it every time I run PowerShell.". It is NOT in any way permanent (I have added an answer that affects a permanent change on this thread).

Comment: This is a good solution, just make sure that concatenating the existing `$env:PATH` won't add stuff you didn't mean to. It's pretty common to modify `PATH` in initialisation scripts and you may not be aware that it's been altered for that specific session. For instance, Powershell 7.0.2 adds itself to `PATH` upon session initialise, so this technique will add that temporary entry every time you call `SetEnvironmentVariable()`. This is just a heads up, as I do think this is the right way of updating the `PATH` permanently.

Comment: >>>`refreshenv`

Comment: @Saito your command does not `set` the `env var` but `add` to the `env var`. This is a difference.

Comment: in `pwsh7`, you see the **change** immediately **without a shell restart**, `refreshenv` here**not necessary**. But the path does not work, i.e. you cannot call a file from the new path without the full path name. This works with a new shell.

Comment: I ended up using this which has a different parameter positioning. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.1#using-systemenvironment-methods

Comment: I was logged in using SSH (i.e., remote machine is Windows PowerShell), and needed to `Restart-Service -Name sshd` for this to take effect.

Comment: Note that $env:Path contains a concatenation of the system environment variable path followed by the user environment variable path. Assigning it like in the last command of the answer will copy the user paths to the system paths, which is very likely not wanted.

Comment: [It doesn't work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76251270/3416774)

Answer (score 82):

WARNING: save a copy of your existing path by doing `$env:path >> a.out` in a PowerShell prompt, in case something goes wrong.

From the PowerShell prompt:

```
setx PATH "$env:path;\the\directory\to\add" -m
```

You should then see the text:

```
SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.
```

Restart your session, and the variable will be available. `setx` can also be used to set arbitrary variables. Type `setx /?` at the prompt for documentation.

Comment: Seems to only work when 'running as administrator', and thereafter takes effect only for 'running as administrator' PowerShell consoles, not regularly running ones.

Comment: Here is some [official Microsoft documentation for Setx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755104(v=ws.10).aspx).

Comment: Ouch - just got hit by the 1024 character limit of setx; thankfully I followed the advice to record the existing value of $end:Path. Just something to be aware of: http://superuser.com/questions/387619/overcoming-the-1024-character-limit-with-setx

Comment: Why not set `$env:PATH` first, then `setx /m PATH "$env:PATH"` so that it applies locally and globally without shell restart?

Comment: Nice! Although setx is not a native cmdlet, still a much better and easily forgotten alternative to those obnoxious long winded .NET Framework calls! It's baffling that even Powershell 7 still doesn't come with an official cmdlet to persist envvars though. What. Feels like a feature that should have parity with 'ls'.

Comment: @matanster -m specifies 'Machine' mode, if you want to set user environment variables, just leave away the -m (or /M)

Comment: @tresf , I think you should post an answer with your solution for setting the variable in the current session as well as in future sessions.

Comment: NB: This set the system path + user path as the path

Comment: This solution is prone to "ERROR: Length of the command line argument should not exceed 255 characters."

Answer (score 50):

## Pain-free, one-line, example solutions

use `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(x,y,"Machine")` and Try these three commands to practice setting and deleting environmental variables in PowerShell.

***Notes on usage***:

1. Run these commands on elevated PowerShell (e.g. with administrator privileges).
2. After every step, to make your commands work, close the session and open it again.

### *Add/create* a ***permanent*** environment variable:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("newEnvVar", "NewEnvVal", "Machine")
```

*`Machine` is an [**`EnvironmentVariableTarget`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environmentvariabletarget?view=net-7.0) that will apply to current and future users, as opposed to the `User` target.*

---

### *Modify/change* environmental variable:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("oldEnvVar", "modifiedEnvVal", "Machine")
```

---

### *Delete/remove* variable:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("oldEnvVar", "", "Machine")
```

Comment: Indeed all those `Setx` & `$Env` answers gave me headache. This one is elegant!

Comment: I also find this problem in my Windows 10 21H2 and PowerShell 5.1 inside Windows Terminal -- We need to close the session and reopen it to check the result. Or both commands -- `$ENV:ALICLOUD_ACCESSKEY_ID` and `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ALICLOUD_ACCESSKEY_ID')` -- will just return you empty result. Is it some kind of bug?

Comment: @JingHe actually i'm not sure we can call it a bug!, it's just the way they design it which i'm not very comfort with it too!

Answer (score 45):

Like [JeanT's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30694253/27581), I wanted an abstraction around adding to the path. Unlike JeanT's answer I needed it to run without user interaction. Other behavior I was looking for:

- Updates `$env:Path` so the change takes effect in the current session
- Persists the environment variable change for future sessions
- Doesn't add a duplicate path when the same path already exists

In case it's useful, here it is:

```
function Add-EnvPath {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $Path,

        [ValidateSet('Machine', 'User', 'Session')]
        [string] $Container = 'Session'
    )

    if ($Container -ne 'Session') {
        $containerMapping = @{
            Machine = [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine
            User = [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User
        }
        $containerType = $containerMapping[$Container]

        $persistedPaths = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', $containerType) -split ';'
        if ($persistedPaths -notcontains $Path) {
            $persistedPaths = $persistedPaths + $Path | where { $_ }
            [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Path', $persistedPaths -join ';', $containerType)
        }
    }

    $envPaths = $env:Path -split ';'
    if ($envPaths -notcontains $Path) {
        $envPaths = $envPaths + $Path | where { $_ }
        $env:Path = $envPaths -join ';'
    }
}
```

Check out [my gist](https://gist.github.com/mkropat/c1226e0cc2ca941b23a9) for the corresponding `Remove-EnvPath` function.

Comment: I added the following small function to my Profile: `function Set-Env ([string]$Name, [string]$Value, [string]$Target = 'User') {
  Set-Item "Env:$Name" $Value
  [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($Name, $Value, $Target)
}
` It makes life so much easier with PowerShell

Answer (score 24):

Although the current accepted answer works in the sense that the path variable gets permanently updated from the context of PowerShell, it doesn't actually update the environment variable stored in the Windows registry.

To achieve that, you can obviously use PowerShell as well:

```
$oldPath=(Get-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH).Path

$newPath=$oldPath+’;C:\NewFolderToAddToTheList\’

Set-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH –Value $newPath
```

More information is in blog post *[Use PowerShell to Modify Your Environmental Path](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/07/23/use-powershell-to-modify-your-environmental-path.aspx)*

If you use PowerShell community extensions, the proper command to add a path to the environment variable path is:

```
Add-PathVariable "C:\NewFolderToAddToTheList" -Target Machine
```

Answer (score 22):

All the answers suggesting a permanent change have the same problem: They break the path registry value.

`SetEnvironmentVariable` turns the `REG_EXPAND_SZ` value `%SystemRoot%\system32`  into a `REG_SZ` value of `C:\Windows\system32`.

Any other variables in the path are lost as well. Adding new ones using `%myNewPath%` won't work any more.

Here's a script `Set-PathVariable.ps1` that I use to address this problem:

```
 [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
 param(
     [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
     [string]$NewLocation)

 Begin
 {

 #requires –runasadministrator

     $regPath = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"
     $hklm = [Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::LocalMachine

     Function GetOldPath()
     {
         $regKey = $hklm.OpenSubKey($regPath, $FALSE)
         $envpath = $regKey.GetValue("Path", "", [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueOptions]::DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames)
         return $envPath
     }
 }

 Process
 {
     # Win32API error codes
     $ERROR_SUCCESS = 0
     $ERROR_DUP_NAME = 34
     $ERROR_INVALID_DATA = 13

     $NewLocation = $NewLocation.Trim();

     If ($NewLocation -eq "" -or $NewLocation -eq $null)
     {
         Exit $ERROR_INVALID_DATA
     }

     [string]$oldPath = GetOldPath
     Write-Verbose "Old Path: $oldPath"

     # Check whether the new location is already in the path
     $parts = $oldPath.split(";")
     If ($parts -contains $NewLocation)
     {
         Write-Warning "The new location is already in the path"
         Exit $ERROR_DUP_NAME
     }

     # Build the new path, make sure we don't have double semicolons
     $newPath = $oldPath + ";" + $NewLocation
     $newPath = $newPath -replace ";;",""

     if ($pscmdlet.ShouldProcess("%Path%", "Add $NewLocation")){

         # Add to the current session
         $env:path += ";$NewLocation"

         # Save into registry
         $regKey = $hklm.OpenSubKey($regPath, $True)
         $regKey.SetValue("Path", $newPath, [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::ExpandString)
         Write-Output "The operation completed successfully."
     }

     Exit $ERROR_SUCCESS
 }
```

I explain the problem in more detail in [a blog post](https://peter.hahndorf.eu/blog/AddingToPathVariable.html).

Comment: Should this be: $newPath = $newPath -replace ";;",";" ?

Answer (score 12):

My suggestion is this one:

I have tested this to add `C:\oracle\x64\bin` to environment variable `Path` permanently and this works fine.

```
$ENV:PATH
```

The first way is simply to do:

```
$ENV:PATH=”$ENV:PATH;c:\path\to\folder”
```

But this change isn’t permanent. `$env:path` will default back to what it was before as soon as you close your PowerShell terminal and reopen it again. That’s because you have applied the change at the session level and not at the source level (which is the registry level). To view the global value of `$env:path`, do:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path ‘Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment’ -Name PATH
```

Or more specifically:

```
(Get-ItemProperty -Path ‘Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment’ -Name PATH).path
```

Now to change this, first we capture the original path that needs to be modified:

```
$oldpath = (Get-ItemProperty -Path ‘Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment’ -Name PATH).path
```

Now we define what the new path should look like. In this case we are appending a new folder:

```
$newpath = “$oldpath;c:\path\to\folder”
```

Note: Be sure that the `$newpath` looks how you want it to look. If not, then you could damage your OS.

Now apply the new value:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path ‘Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment’ -Name PATH -Value $newPath
```

Now do one final check that it looks like how you expect it to:

```
(Get-ItemProperty -Path ‘Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment’ -Name PATH).Path
```

You can now restart your PowerShell terminal (or even reboot the machine) and see that it doesn’t rollback to its old value again.

Note the ordering of the paths may change so that it’s in alphabetical order, so make sure you check the whole line. To make it easier, you can split the output into rows by using the semi-colon as a delimiter:

```
($env:path).split(“;”)
```

Answer (score 10):

This sets the path for the current session and prompts the user to add it permanently:

```
function Set-Path {
    param([string]$x)
    $Env:Path+= ";" +  $x
    Write-Output $Env:Path
    $write = Read-Host 'Set PATH permanently ? (yes|no)'
    if ($write -eq "yes")
    {
        [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path",$env:Path, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
        Write-Output 'PATH updated'
    }
}
```

You can add this function to your default profile, (`Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`), usually located at `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell`.

Answer (score 10):

Building on [@Michael Kropat's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34844707/1509300) answer I added a parameter to prepend the new path to the existing `PATH`variable and a check to avoid the addition of a non-existing path:

```
function Add-EnvPath {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $Path,

        [ValidateSet('Machine', 'User', 'Session')]
        [string] $Container = 'Session',

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
        [Switch] $Prepend
    )

    if (Test-Path -path "$Path") {
        if ($Container -ne 'Session') {
            $containerMapping = @{
                Machine = [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine
                User = [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User
            }
            $containerType = $containerMapping[$Container]

            $persistedPaths = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', $containerType) -split ';'
            if ($persistedPaths -notcontains $Path) {
                if ($Prepend) {
                    $persistedPaths = ,$Path + $persistedPaths | where { $_ }
                    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Path', $persistedPaths -join ';', $containerType)
                }
                else {
                    $persistedPaths = $persistedPaths + $Path | where { $_ }
                    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Path', $persistedPaths -join ';', $containerType)
                }
            }
        }

        $envPaths = $env:Path -split ';'
        if ($envPaths -notcontains $Path) {
            if ($Prepend) {
                $envPaths = ,$Path + $envPaths | where { $_ }
                $env:Path = $envPaths -join ';'
            }
            else {
                $envPaths = $envPaths + $Path | where { $_ }
                $env:Path = $envPaths -join ';'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Only the answers that push the value into the registry affect a *permanent* change (so the majority of answers on this thread, including the accepted answer, do *not* permanently affect the `Path`).

The following function works for both `Path` / `PSModulePath` and for `User` / `System` types. It will also add the new path to the current session by default.

```
function AddTo-Path {
    param ( 
        [string]$PathToAdd,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateSet('System','User')][string]$UserType,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateSet('Path','PSModulePath')][string]$PathType
    )

    # AddTo-Path "C:\XXX" "PSModulePath" 'System' 
    if ($UserType -eq "System" ) { $RegPropertyLocation = 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' }
    if ($UserType -eq "User"   ) { $RegPropertyLocation = 'HKCU:\Environment' } # also note: Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\ format
    $PathOld = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $RegPropertyLocation -Name $PathType).$PathType
    "`n$UserType $PathType Before:`n$PathOld`n"
    $PathArray = $PathOld -Split ";" -replace "\\+$", ""
    if ($PathArray -notcontains $PathToAdd) {
        "$UserType $PathType Now:"   # ; sleep -Milliseconds 100   # Might need pause to prevent text being after Path output(!)
        $PathNew = "$PathOld;$PathToAdd"
        Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegPropertyLocation -Name $PathType -Value $PathNew
        Get-ItemProperty -Path $RegPropertyLocation -Name $PathType | select -ExpandProperty $PathType
        if ($PathType -eq "Path") { $env:Path += ";$PathToAdd" }                  # Add to Path also for this current session
        if ($PathType -eq "PSModulePath") { $env:PSModulePath += ";$PathToAdd" }  # Add to PSModulePath also for this current session
        "`n$PathToAdd has been added to the $UserType $PathType"
    }
    else {
        "'$PathToAdd' is already in the $UserType $PathType. Nothing to do."
    }
}

# Add "C:\XXX" to User Path (but only if not already present)
AddTo-Path "C:\XXX" "User" "Path"

# Just show the current status by putting an empty path
AddTo-Path "" "User" "Path"
```

Answer (score 7):

Within PowerShell, one can navigate to the environment variable directory by typing:

```
Set-Location Env:
```

This will bring you to the Env:> directory. From within this directory:

To see all environment variables, type:

```
Env:\> Get-ChildItem
```

To see a specific environment variable, type:

```
Env:\> $Env:<variable name>, e.g. $Env:Path
```

To set an environment variable, type:

```
Env:\> $Env:<variable name> = "<new-value>", e.g. $Env:Path="C:\Users\"
```

To remove an environment variable, type:

```
Env:\> remove-item Env:<variable name>, e.g. remove-item Env:SECRET_KEY
```

More information is in *[About Environment Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-6)*.

Answer (score 6):

As [Jonathan Leaders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1689770/jonathan-leaders) mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28596275), it is important to run the command/script elevated to be able to change environment variables for **'machine'**, but running some commands elevated doesn't have to be done with the Community Extensions, so I'd like to modify and extend [JeanT's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1116269/jeant) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30694253) in a way, that changing machine variables also can be performed even if the script itself isn't run elevated:

```cs
function Set-Path ([string]$newPath, [bool]$permanent=$false, [bool]$forMachine=$false )
{
    $Env:Path += ";$newPath"

    $scope = if ($forMachine) { 'Machine' } else { 'User' }

    if ($permanent)
    {
        $command = "[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', $env:Path, $scope)"
        Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-noprofile -command $Command" -Verb runas
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Most answers aren't addressing [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control). This covers UAC issues.

First install PowerShell Community Extensions: `choco install pscx` via http://chocolatey.org/ (you may have to restart your shell environment).

Then enable pscx

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser #allows scripts to run from the interwebs, such as pcsx
```

Then use `Invoke-Elevated`

```
Invoke-Elevated {Add-PathVariable $args[0] -Target Machine} -ArgumentList $MY_NEW_DIR
```

Answer (score 4):

To be clear, the 1990's Windows way of click on **Start**, right click on **This PC**, and choose **Properties**, and then select **Advanced system settings**, and then in the dialog box that pops up, select **Environment Variables**, and in the list double clicking on **PATH** and then using the **New**, **Edit**, **Move Up** and **Move Down** all still work for changing the PATH.  Power shell, and the rest of Windows get whatever you set here.

Yes you can use these new methods, but the old one still works.  And at the base level all of the permanent change methods are controlled ways of editing your registry files.

Comment: This *is* a PowerShell question, so the answer should be as well.

Answer (score 3):

Open PowerShell and run:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", "$ENV:PATH;<path to exe>", "USER")
```

Answer (score 3):

These scripts are idempotent (can be run more than once).
They update both the Windows path and the current / future Powershell sessions:

## Permanently add path

```
    $targetDir="c:\bin"
    $oldPath = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine")
    $oldPathArray=($oldPath) -split ';'
    if(-Not($oldPathArray -Contains "$targetDir")) {
        write-host "Adding $targetDir to Machine Path"
        $newPath = "$oldPath;$targetDir" -replace ';+', ';'
        [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path",$newPath,"Machine")
        $env:Path = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","User"),[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine") -join ";"
    }
    write-host "Windows paths:"
    ($env:Path).Replace(';',"`n")
```

## Permanently remove path

```
    $targetDir="c:\bin"
    $oldPath = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine")
    $oldPathArray=($oldPath) -split ';'
    if($oldPathArray -Contains "$targetDir") {
        write-host "Removing $targetDir from Machine path"
        $newPathArray = $oldPathArray | Where-Object { $_ –ne "$targetDir" }
        $newPath = $newPathArray -join ";"
        [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path",$newPath,"Machine")
        $env:Path = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","User"),[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine") -join ";"
    }
    write-host "Windows paths:"
    ($env:Path).Replace(';',"`n")
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution that I found to add `C:\vcpkg` **permanently** to my `PATH` env variable without drawbacks was :

```
$current_PATH = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", "USER");[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", "$current_PATH;C:\vcpkg;", "USER")
```

You can change `"USER"` to `"MACHINE"` to change system env vars (need an admin terminal and you may need to change `Environment` to `System.Environment`) or even to `"PROCESS"` to only change local `PATH` env var (not permanently changed). Respectively `"USER"=1` `"MACHINE"=2` and `"PROCESS"=0` here are the documentation about those commands: [GetEnvironmentVariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=net-7.0) [SetEnvironmentVariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environmentvariabletarget?view=net-7.0)

Two other answers that I found but have major drawbacks and ***I do not recommend to use them***. Both use `SETX` as it is implemented by PowerShell to change permanently env variable. The down side of those commandes are that you will **duplicate your system PATH** into your locale PATH and you need PowerShell to use them:

```
setx PATH "$($Env:PATH);C:\vcpkg;"
```

Longer but allow an usage with other env variable:

```
$($Env:PATH).Split(';') | %{ $str += "$($_.Trim('"'));" }; %{ $str += "C:\vcpkg;" } ; setx PATH $str; %{ $str = "" }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to set variable name dynamically and for session only, then use:

```
New-Item env:\$key -Value $value -Force | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to optimise [SBF's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714877/setting-windows-powershell-environment-variables/48624689#48624689) and [Michael's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714877/setting-windows-powershell-environment-variables/34844707#34844707) code a bit to make it more compact.

I am relying on PowerShell's type coercion where it automatically converts strings to enum values, so I didn't define the lookup dictionary.

I also pulled out the block that adds the new path to the list based on a condition, so that work is done once and stored in a variable for re-use.

It is then applied permanently or just to the Session depending on the `$PathContainer` parameter.

We can put the block of code in a function or a ps1 file that we call directly from the command prompt. I went with DevEnvAddPath.ps1.

```
param(
    [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true)][String]$PathChange,

    [ValidateSet('Machine', 'User', 'Session')]
    [Parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=$false)][String]$PathContainer='Session',
    [Parameter(Position=2,Mandatory=$false)][Boolean]$PathPrepend=$false
)

[String]$ConstructedEnvPath = switch ($PathContainer) { "Session"{${env:Path};} default{[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', $containerType);} };
$PathPersisted = $ConstructedEnvPath -split ';';

if ($PathPersisted -notcontains $PathChange) {
    $PathPersisted = $(switch ($PathPrepend) { $true{,$PathChange + $PathPersisted;} default{$PathPersisted + $PathChange;} }) | Where-Object { $_ };

    $ConstructedEnvPath = $PathPersisted -join ";";
}

if ($PathContainer -ne 'Session') 
{
    # Save permanently to Machine, User
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $ConstructedEnvPath, $PathContainer);
}

# Update the current session
${env:Path} = $ConstructedEnvPath;
```

I do something similar for a DevEnvRemovePath.ps1.

```
param(
    [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true)][String]$PathChange,

    [ValidateSet('Machine', 'User', 'Session')]
    [Parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=$false)][String]$PathContainer='Session'
)

[String]$ConstructedEnvPath = switch ($PathContainer) { "Session"{${env:Path};} default{[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', $containerType);} };
$PathPersisted = $ConstructedEnvPath -split ';';

if ($PathPersisted -contains $PathChange) {
    $PathPersisted = $PathPersisted | Where-Object { $_ -ne $PathChange };

    $ConstructedEnvPath = $PathPersisted -join ";";
}

if ($PathContainer -ne 'Session') 
{
    # Save permanently to Machine, User
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $ConstructedEnvPath, $PathContainer);
}

# Update the current session
${env:Path} = $ConstructedEnvPath;
```

So far, they seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of examples of appending, or overwriting. Here is an example of prepending a path on powershell for Linux, Ubuntu 18.04 with `pwsh` 7.1.3

```
$ENV:PATH = "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:$ENV:PATH"
```

I'm specifically adding the linuxbrew (homebrew for linux) bin directory to take precedence over the system installed. It helped solve an issue I was having and although this was the most helpful place, it also left me "experimenting".

Note that the `:` is Linux path separator, whereas on Windows (or at least my windows) you would use `;` for powershell typically.

Answer (score 0):

Editing the registry key in [@ali Darabi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48113366/2234009) worked best for me, but
When I didn't have the right permissions to do it from Powershell. So I edited it directly in regedit.

I want to expand further on the subject in this answer.

Restarting Powershell also wasn't sufficient to propagate the change. I had to Open Task Manager and restart explorer.exe to trigger a reload of the registry.

It can be quite tedious to navigate the registry so in order to maintain an user friendly experience you can execute this from Powershell:

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\Regedit" /v "LastKey" /d "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /f; regedit
```

It sets the last opened window to a certain registry path, so that when you open regedit the next time it opens at the proper key.

Answer (score -2):

To add the environment variables in the Windows container, follow the below steps

Add environment variable in the dockerfile ENV MYENVVAR

RUN $env:MYENVVAR

docker run -e MYENVVAR=<ACTUVAL_VALUE>

Comment: PowerShell doesn't use Docker by default.