# How can I do a screen capture in Windows PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

How can I capture the screen in Windows PowerShell?   I need to be able to save the screen to disk.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can also use .NET to take the screenshot programatically (which gives you finer control):

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
function screenshot([Drawing.Rectangle]$bounds, $path) {
   $bmp = New-Object Drawing.Bitmap $bounds.width, $bounds.height
   $graphics = [Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($bmp)

   $graphics.CopyFromScreen($bounds.Location, [Drawing.Point]::Empty, $bounds.size)

   $bmp.Save($path)

   $graphics.Dispose()
   $bmp.Dispose()
}

$bounds = [Drawing.Rectangle]::FromLTRB(0, 0, 1000, 900)
screenshot $bounds "C:\screenshot.png"
```

Comment: Great - how hard would it be to get this to capture the window of a specific application ? I am creating an IE instance like this : $ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application" - would it be possible to capture just the output of this window for instance ?

Comment: @jeremy tried on windows 10, doesn't work: output nothing.

Comment: @user310291 the code itself still works, but you need to change the path from "C:\screenshot.png" to some location you can write to, e.g. your desktop.

Answer (score 17):

For the sake of completion, this script allows you to take screenshots across multiple monitors.

The base code comes from [Jeremy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2970339/1073358).

```
function screenshot($path)
{
    [void] [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
    [void] [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
    $left = [Int32]::MaxValue
    $top = [Int32]::MaxValue
    $right = [Int32]::MinValue
    $bottom = [Int32]::MinValue

    foreach ($screen in [Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens)
    {
        if ($screen.Bounds.X -lt $left)
        {
            $left = $screen.Bounds.X;
        }
        if ($screen.Bounds.Y -lt $top)
        {
            $top = $screen.Bounds.Y;
        }
        if ($screen.Bounds.X + $screen.Bounds.Width -gt $right)
        {
            $right = $screen.Bounds.X + $screen.Bounds.Width;
        }
        if ($screen.Bounds.Y + $screen.Bounds.Height -gt $bottom)
        {
            $bottom = $screen.Bounds.Y + $screen.Bounds.Height;
        }
    }

    $bounds = [Drawing.Rectangle]::FromLTRB($left, $top, $right, $bottom);
    $bmp = New-Object Drawing.Bitmap $bounds.Width, $bounds.Height;
    $graphics = [Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($bmp);

    $graphics.CopyFromScreen($bounds.Location, [Drawing.Point]::Empty, $bounds.size);

    $bmp.Save($path);

    $graphics.Dispose();
    $bmp.Dispose();
}
```

It can be called with:
screenshot "D:\screenshot.png"

Comment: This solution will be thrown off by DPI scaling. To avoid that, you'd p/invoke. And even then, getting per-monitor scaling information is tricky. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69786234/disable-high-dpi-scaling

Answer (score 12):

This PowerShell function will capture the screen in PowerShell and save it to an automatically numbered file.  If the -OfWindow switch is used, then the current window will be captured.

This works by using the built in PRINTSCREEN / CTRL-PRINTSCREEEN tricks, and it uses a bitmap encoder to save the file to disk.

```
function Get-ScreenCapture
{
    param(
    [Switch]$OfWindow
    )


    begin {
        Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
        $jpegCodec = [Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo]::GetImageEncoders() |
            Where-Object { $_.FormatDescription -eq "JPEG" }
    }
    process {
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250
        if ($OfWindow) {
            [Windows.Forms.Sendkeys]::SendWait("%{PrtSc}")
        } else {
            [Windows.Forms.Sendkeys]::SendWait("{PrtSc}")
        }
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250
        $bitmap = [Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::GetImage()
        $ep = New-Object Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters
        $ep.Param[0] = New-Object Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameter ([System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder]::Quality, [long]100)
        $screenCapturePathBase = "$pwd\ScreenCapture"
        $c = 0
        while (Test-Path "${screenCapturePathBase}${c}.jpg") {
            $c++
        }
        $bitmap.Save("${screenCapturePathBase}${c}.jpg", $jpegCodec, $ep)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there additional steps needed to get this to work on Windows 7 ? I'm getting the following error when running the function:"Unable to find type [Windows.Forms.Sendkeys]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded." and then a further error "Unable to find type [Windows.Forms.Clipboard]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded." , and then one more error (but I think because the previous two calls failed).

Comment: You  probably haven't loaded Winforms.  I'd recommend you  simply download the module this answer is now in:  [RoughDraft](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/RoughDraft-cfeb6e98)

Comment: For future readers, adding `Add-Type -assembly System.Windows.Forms` before the function fixes the issue mentioned by @monojohnny

Answer (score 9):

Here is my solution for multi-monitor, which is a bit simpler than the current answer. It also will render screens properly if the user has a strange monitor config (stacked vertical, etc) without black bars.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms,System.Drawing

$screens = [Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens

$top    = ($screens.Bounds.Top    | Measure-Object -Minimum).Minimum
$left   = ($screens.Bounds.Left   | Measure-Object -Minimum).Minimum
$right  = ($screens.Bounds.Right  | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum
$bottom = ($screens.Bounds.Bottom | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum

$bounds   = [Drawing.Rectangle]::FromLTRB($left, $top, $right, $bottom)
$bmp      = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap ([int]$bounds.width), ([int]$bounds.height)
$graphics = [Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($bmp)

$graphics.CopyFromScreen($bounds.Location, [Drawing.Point]::Empty, $bounds.size)

$bmp.Save("$env:USERPROFILE\test.png")

$graphics.Dispose()
$bmp.Dispose()
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"the current answer"*? [The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969321/how-can-i-do-a-screen-capture-in-windows-powershell/2970339#2970339)?

Comment: The currently most upvoted answer for multi-monitor: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44609221/4868262

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft have a PowerShell script available here:

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/eeff544a-f690-4f6b-a586-11eea6fc5eb8

I have just tried it on a Windows 7 machine and it to work, using the commandline example provided:

```
Take-ScreenShot -screen -file "C:\image.png" -imagetype png
```

Comment: Where do you place this .ps1 file so you don't have to type the entire network path in ?

Comment: @Aaron, not quite sure how best to do this - but probably set it in Powershell profile (perhaps either by editing PATH variable, or using an alias) : this article may help :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714877/setting-windows-powershell-path-variable

Comment: Open with... produces no outcome. Input in console then invoking it produces no input either. This is Windows 10 and this thread has been here for years without producing input.

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken. It redirects to the ***unspecific*** URL `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/browse/?redirectedfrom=TechNet-Gallery`.