# Saving images automatically on just clicking of print screen keyboard button with Windows Power shell?

Tags: powershell-3.0, powershell-ise

Is there a way to save images automatically on just clicking of print screen button on keyboard with the help of Windows Power shell? I am new to Windows Powershell.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I do a screen capture in Windows PowerShell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969321/how-can-i-do-a-screen-capture-in-windows-powershell)