# What coding languages would I need to code my own screen recording software?

Tags: coding-style, audio-recording, video-recording, voice-recording, desktop-recording

I would like to make a screen recorder, but I'm not sure what code I will need once I have all the languages then i will be fine. Does anyone know what languages would be needed or suggest to use? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, use one of the CLR languages (C#, F#...), for Mac OS use Objective-C. In general, use the programming languages which are very well integrated with the platform you targeting, because you need to access the APIs of the platform directly.

Answer (score 0):

There is lots of good information about this on stackoverflow already.

It will depend largely on your platform and what exactly you are trying to screen capture.

Assuming you are trying to capture a single frame of your desktop with only normal applications running, you can do what you want with scripting languages.

For example:
On OSX you can use [Applescript to capture screens](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113416/automate-taking-a-screenshot-of-specified-area).
On Windows you can use [Powershell to capture screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969321/how-can-i-do-a-screen-capture-in-windows-powershell).
On Linux you can use [Python to capture screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645/take-a-screenshot-via-a-python-script-linux).

You can extend these to capture a movie as opposed to a single frame.

Of course none of these approaches will work for some applications (like protected video players) and you will probably have to write some driver-level code to capture these correctly. I usually use C/C++ to write those, but whatever has good driver-level support on your system will work.