# Export powershell screen output as image

Tags: powershell

How do I export the output in powershell screen and save it as a image?
To save the output as a text file I use the command below:

`script.ps1 >> output.txt`

I would want the output to be saved as a screenshot or image.  Tried exporting as:

`script.ps1 >> output.png`

The image doesn't open

Comment: How do you expect the image to be? the console it self?

Comment: Yes. A screenshot of the console itself.

Comment: I am not sure how you would take a screenshot of just the Powershell console, but you could take one of the entire screen: [How can I do a screen capture in Windows PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969321/how-can-i-do-a-screen-capture-in-windows-powershell)

Answer (score 1):

This might point you in the right direction.  Although it does not it does not directly output the console to a png file you could output the console to a txt file and then using Get-Content export this to a png file

https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/8rg3hc/exportpng/