# PowerShell issue - I have to type ./ to run bat file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I've just installed PHP & Yii Framework. It works fine, I played with CMD. But after a while I switched to PowerShell ISE. I navigated to Yii folder:

> cd C:\dev\yii-1.1.9.r3527\framework

and I issued command:

> yiic.bat

and I get an error:

```
PS C:\dev\yii-1.1.9.r3527\framework> yiic.bat
The term 'yiic.bat' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:9
+ yiic.bat <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (yiic.bat:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

However when I type:

> ./yiic.bat

into PowerShell window, it works fine.

Is there a way to aviod typing **./** every time I run a **bat** file?

Answer (score 4):

The `framework` directory you're trying to run the batch file from is evidently not in your path.  When you type `yiic.bat` into the shell, it looks for that file in the list of directories contained in your `path` environment variable.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714877/setting-windows-powershell-path-variable) for information about how to set your `path` in powershell.

For example, if you want to be able to run batch files in the `C:\dev\yii-1.1.9.r3527\framework` directory, you can say `$env:Path = $env:Path + ";C:\dev\yii-1.1.9.r3527\framework"`.

Or, as mloskot says, you can just add the current directory to your path, though that can pose a minor security risk.  See e.g. [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/98587/adding-current-directory-to-path) for a bit of discussion on that.

Answer (score 4):

this is an old question, but I stumbled on it looking for something else.
Powershell requires you to type .\ to run commands in the current by design.
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/csps/2010/06/06/introduction-to-windows-powershell-scripting/

Answer (score 2):

I don't have PowerShell to try this out, but if you set the path to include current folder, this should work:

```
$env:Path = $env:Path + ";."
```

Comment: Or just `$Env:Path += ';.'`.