# sass not recognised using Windows command shell

Tags: ruby, sass

I've installed ruby and the sass gem on a Win 7 Enterprise box. I've had issues throughout the process, and had to download the gems and install them from local to avoid other issues.

```
gem install --local sass-3.1.19.gem
```

I'm trying `sass --watch styles.sass:styles.css` but I get the standard sass isn't recognised error from the command line.

I'm really new to ruby so I could well have missed a step.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have the gem folder in your `$PATH`?

Comment: I don't know much about windows, but read this http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/command_line.shtml#path

Comment: Old thread but I found it when trying to use SASS on Windows, in the end I used 'Koala' for compilation which turned out GREAT: http://bobmckay.com/web/sass-css/sass-windows-tutorial-automatic-sass-compilation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to run commands without specifying full path, you need to have the path to the program in you `PATH` variable.

So if your program is located in `C:\Programs\rubygems\gem\sass` you'll need to add `C:\Programs\rubygems\gem\` to `PATH`.

The process of adding a folder to `PATH` for the Windows command line prompt is described [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/command_line.shtml#path).

For Windows Powershell, please check [Setting Windows PowerShell path variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714877/setting-windows-powershell-path-variable) here on SO.

Comment: As an addition, I found it was necessary to restart `cmd` to get `sass` to appear in the command line

Comment: You don't necessarily need to restart `cmd`, but you need to reload the environment variables. I guess reastarting is the easiest way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

After installing sass with NPM you got this:

```
npm install -g sass
```

> file:///C:/Users/yourName/AppData/Roaming/npm/sass ->
>   C:/Users/Administrador/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/sass/sass.js

You can create the path. Go to environment variables - > system variables -> path -> Edith , and include file:///C:/Users/yourName/AppData/Roaming/npm/sass. Then, Accept everything. and it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, putting the path to my ruby bin did indeed solve this.

My Computer --> right click, Properties --> Advanced system settings (left hand column) --> Environment variables --> find Path in the bottom list, highlight and edit --> include ;c:\path-to-ruby\bin at the end --> OK back out through the windows.

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah... If you put it in an answer I'll mark it as the answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you using `Windows 10 v1607 (latest update as March 2017)`, you need to follow following steps:

1. Right-click on start menu & select `System`
2. Click on `Advanced System Settings` *(left hand column)*
3. Click on `Environment variables` button
4. In top section, select `Path` (or `PATH`), then click on `Edit` button
5. Inside opened window, click on `New` button
6. In selected input area, type (for ex.) `C:\Ruby22-x64\bin\` *(its must be path to ruby's bin folder)*
7. Click `OK`, twice
8. Re-open `Command-Prompt`, now `sass` is ready to watch and compile your sass files.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Node installed use the node terminal instead of the windows/VSCode terminal.

Search for the Node terminal on the windows search tool placed on the right side of the windows start button.