# Sass error when trying to create input / output

Tags: css, sass

Can't create input/output in Sass. Sass and node seem to be installed fine, when in VS code terminal I try to create my input / output documents I get an error. Running Windows OS.

I also can't seem to change dir, or do many commands that tutorials seem to use in my cmd even when running as administrator. I can't even seem to cd in cmd, so would love some help there.

I have tried running as administrator, tried installing -g gem something or other. I've watched tutorials and crawled through the net for a few hours and am spinning my wheels.

I will try uninstalling / reinstalling asap or will use koala or something similar for now.

```
C:\Users\jdven\Desktop\CSSdev\Week9> sass input.scss output.css
```

I get

sass : The term 'sass' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

I should be getting an SCSS document that allows me to compile scss to css when I output. I'm trying to be able watch a doc then output.

```
sass : The term 'sass' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if 
a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ sass input.scss output.css
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (sass:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: You could install node https://nodejs.org/en/download/, then run `npm i node-sass -g` and then `npx node-sass -w input.scss output.scss` (The w means that it will watch the input for changes https://github.com/sass/node-sass/blob/master/README.md#usage-1)

Comment: For me it looks like windows does not recognize sass as a global command. Maybe setting a path variable will do the trick. Here is a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259140/sass-not-recognised-using-windows-command-shell) on stack overflow that could help you with this.