# issue in setting path for django and pip in windows 7

Tags: django

I am new in django and python.I am using windows 7 and Eclipse IDE.I have installed python 2.7,django and pip.I have created a system variable called PYTHONPATH with values `C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts`.I am unable to set path for django and pip.When i type django-admin.py and pip in powershell,it shows `commandnotfoundexception.`I have attached screen shots of my django files and pip files.[image][image]
Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the Powershell specific path variable.  It does not know to look for an environment variable called `pythonpath`.  That is helpful only for python aware applications (such as installers for Python modules).

You need to add the Python directories to the `$env:Path` environment variable in Powershell.  See [Setting Windows PowerShell path variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714877/setting-windows-powershell-path-variable)

> $env:Path += ";C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts"

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you're just getting started with Django and Eclipse, make sure you configure your PyDev interpreter settings to include the site-packages directory.  This will ensure Eclipse can find your Django packages.

You can find more details about setting up your PYTHONPATH inside Eclipse here:

[PyDev Interpreter Configuration](http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html)