# Showing error "nvmw command not found" when setting the path of nvmw in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I am new in Nodejs.  I want to install nvmw in my system. For that first I clone the respiratory using this command

```
git clone git://github.com/hakobera/nvmw.git "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\.nvmw"
```

after that for activating nvmw, I used this command

```
set "PATH=%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\.nvmw;%PATH%"
```

in E drive.Folder is also created in E drive in name of `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` and inside the folder all the datas and nvmw folder also created.

But after that when I am running this command `nvmw help`, it shows "nvmw command not found". I tried by changing the folder name also but it shows the same error. I think I am doing some mistake in setting the path.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, that command is not working on Windows PowerShell.
The command for setting System Path should be run Windows Command Prompt.

In the other hands, you can add installed path with GUI.

For Windows PowerShell, see following question: 
[Setting Windows PowerShell path variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714877)