# How to invoke cmake from powershell using MinGW generator

Tags: c++, powershell, cmake

I am trying to invoke cmake from powershell so that I can build project with MinGW compiler. It works fine for Visual Studio generator, and it also work when I use cmake-gui, however from powershell I get this error:

```
cmake ..\..\huggle -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Qt\Tools\mingw491_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Qt/Tools/mingw491_32/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Qt/Tools/mingw491_32/bin/gcc.exe -- broken
cmake : CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.1/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
At line:1 char:1
+ cmake ..\..\huggle -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Qt\Tools\mingw49 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CMake Error at ...e:61 (message)::String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Some kind of switch that would make cmake be more verbose about the error would be nice, when I run cmake using gui I get this output:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.1
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Qt/Tools/mingw491_32/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Qt/Tools/mingw491_32/bin/gcc.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Qt/Tools/mingw491_32/bin/g++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Qt/Tools/mingw491_32/bin/g++.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PythonLibs: C:/Python34/libs/libpython34.a (found version "3.4.1") 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

Answer (score 2):

I've tested your powershell `cmake` call and could reproduce the problem if I *don't* have MinGw in my `PATH` environment variable:

```
PS> cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.3/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:54 (message):
  The C++ compiler "C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe" is not able to compile a simple
  test program.
```

Actually I got some error popups saying `cc1plus.exe has stopped working`. This file has some dependencies to DLLs in the `MinGW\bin` path (in my installation e.g. `libgmp-10.dll`, `libmpc-3.dll` or `libmpfr-4.dll`). I've used Microsoft's [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to analyze the the problem.

But I have also had very good results checking for unhandled MinGW exceptions using/installing [Dr. Mingw](https://github.com/jrfonseca/drmingw).

**Conclusion**

I'm pretty sure that a direct call to `C:\Qt\Tools\mingw491_32\bin\g++.exe` from your powershell will fail. So the most likely reason in your example is a missing MinGW search path in your `PATH` environment variable:

```
PS> $env:Path += ";C:\Qt\Tools\mingw491_32\bin"
PS> cmake ..\..\huggle -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Qt\Tools\mingw491_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe
```

With the additonal search path it was working in my environment.

**References**

- [Setting Windows PowerShell path variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714877/setting-windows-powershell-path-variable)