# PHP7 not working from the command line

Tags: php

I just installed PHP7 on my windows 10 machine from here (the thread safe 64 bit version) http://windows.php.net/download#php-7.0

I manually set the path to the php folder and set up the `php.ini`.
Whenever I want to use the php command it just goes into the next line without doing anything. It doesn't even matter what arguments I type in. There is no error message so I am clueless on what could be the problem.

Here is what happens:

```
PS C:\Users\Jakob> php
PS C:\Users\Jakob> php cjasdf
PS C:\Users\Jakob>
```

Even if i navigate into the php folder and execute the php.exe nothing happens as well:

```
PS C:\php> .\php.exe
PS C:\php> .\php.exe aleass
PS C:\php>
```

Comment: If you didn't put the path to php's folder into the environment variable `PATH` then you need to use the full path to php.

Comment: Try this `php -v` what does that give you

Comment: Oh PHP 7 is now at version  PHP7.0.2, wont be part of this problem but why start 2 steps back from current

Comment: `php -v` doesn't give any output

Comment: OK Assuming PHP installed into `C:\php` do a `cd \php` and then run `php -v` or `php -ini`

Comment: Also try using a standard Command Window instead of Power Shell

Comment: ok thanks! using normal Command Window gave me an error. `VCRUNTIME140.dll` seems to be missing

Comment: Well then the first thing you need to do is update Windows with that runtime library from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RE: Your comment about a missing Visual C/C++ runtime library

The first thing you need to do is update Windows with that runtime library [Download it from here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145)

Ok Power Shell is A completely different beast to the command prompt and all the usual DOS commands are replaced with PS commands

I got PHP to run in Power Shell like this

Running PHP by switching into the folder where PHP is installed

```
 PS > Set-Location c:\php
 PS > php -v
```

And here is how I would do it better, by adding the `C:\php` folder to the PATH, but only for the duration of the PS Windows instance i.e. not a permanant change to the Windows PATH

Add your PHP folder to the WINDOWS PATH for the duration of this PS execution

```
PS > $ENV:Path = $ENV:Path + ";c:\php"
```

The CD (or the PS equivalent) into the folder containing your PHP CLI scripts

```
PS > Set-Location c:\php-source
PS > php test.php
```

Thanks, I have never used Power Shell before and finding this simple stuff out made me think I should spend some time learning more about it.

Comment: This may also help if you insist on using PS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714877/setting-windows-powershell-path-variable