# How to deploy asp.net application to docker container on Linux server?

Tags: asp.net, docker, visual-studio-2015, dnx

I have installed docker engine on a Linux server. On my desktop's Visual Studio 2015, I created an asp.net application. Now I want to publish it to the Linux server and create a docker image.

I followed this [step](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PublishingAnASPNET5AppToDockerOnLinuxWithVisualStudio.aspx).

[image: 2]

I don't have an azure account and I want to use my own Linux server. So next, I clicked the `Docker Containers`. The interface became:

[image: 3]

Then I clicked `Custom Docker Host` and pressed OK button.

The interface was

[image: 4]

Now I input the image name as `DockerDemo`. Also I type the server url something like `tcp://12.16.45.56:8080`. Validate connection is okay then go to the next step.

Finally I get this:

[image: 5]

However I get an error during publish.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       An error occured during publish.
>   The command [docker -H tcp://12.16.45.56:8080 build -t DockerDemo -f "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\DockerDemo63\approot\src\DockerDemo\Dockerfile" "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\DockerDemo63"] exited with code [1](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PublishingAnASPNET5AppToDockerOnLinuxWithVisualStudio.aspx): 'docker' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   Please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=529706 for troubleshooting guide.   DockerDemo      0

By the way, the framework I am using is:

```
  "frameworks": {
  "dnx451": { },
  "dnxcore50": { }
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Well it sounds like it's trying to run docker but it's not appearing on the path it's trying to run from. Probably a bug, as it should know where to find it. But as a workaround, try adding the path to the Docker executable to your system's PATH environment variable, then restart Visual Studio and try again.

Comment: @mason, forgiving my ignorance. What is the path to the Docker executable? Can you give me an example?

Comment: I've got no idea. Use a tool to search your computer for it? Or [install it yourself](https://docs.docker.com/windows/)?

Comment: @mason, sorry for my unclear statement. I wrote the asp.net on my Windows 7 desktop. But the docker container should be on a remote Linux server. My Windows desktop doesn't have docker installed.

Comment: The point is that Visual Studio needs Docker installed (on your development Windows box) in order to create a Docker container that you can then deploy to your Linux box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio can't find the `docker` command on your local computer.  It needs this as a client to connect to the docker daemon on your Linux server.  The easiest way to do this is to install Docker Toolbox from here:

https://www.docker.com/products/docker-toolbox

You may have to uninstall and re-install "Visual Studio 2015 Tools for Docker" or manually add to Powershell's `$env:Path` if the docker command still can't be found.

Also, your Image Name must not contain uppercase characters.  Use `dockerdemo` rather than `DockerDemo`.

Comment: I installed the toolbox and the environment variable `PATH` includes it now. Why it still fails? I have `docker.exe` under C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox;

Comment: Is Docker.exe on your PATH?  Failing that, have you restarted VS.NET?  Does the error message change at all?

Comment: Yes, I am sure and I restarted VS. Same error message.

Comment: No, if you referring to type the command as `PS C:\Users\Me> docker`.  The term is not recognized. But I check the `PATH` variable, it(C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox;) is there. Under that folder, there is `docker.exe`.

Comment: Docker Toolbox is listed as a pre-requisite for the installation of VS 2015 Tools for Docker.  It might be simplest to remove and re-install the Tools.  Or you can change the Powershell path here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714877/setting-windows-powershell-path-variable

Comment: First of all, uninstall and reinstall VS 2015 Tools for Docker is still not working. Secondly, I run the command `$env:Path` in PowerShell and found the folder `C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox` is not there. So I run `$env:path +=';C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox'` and verified it is executing now. However when I published it, I got a different error. `exited with code [125]: invalid value "DockerDemo" for flag -t: Error parsing reference: "DockerDemo" is not a valid repository/tag
See 'docker build --help'.`

Comment: I have added to the answer - your image name should not contain upper case characters.