# Trouble running EXE when called from Powershell

Tags: powershell

Full script here: https://gist.github.com/sithtoast/92ee19119e73ced8b159f388af4f8892

I am attempting to run an EXE from Powershell in an effort to automate things. The problem I'm running into is that when this certain EXE is called from Powershell, it does not run properly.

Elaborating on "not running properly": There is a stage of the installer that it backs up parts of the registry and fails there. The exact error is as follows -

> Could not launch process regedit.exe /s "C:\Program
>   Files\EVault\InfoStage\Director\~registry-1b683bce-c303-4c9b-8ccd-77b750318005\regbackup.reg"
>   (The system cannot find the file specified.), error code: 2

However, when I browse to said EXE manually and run it - it works just fine. Other EXEs that are called the exact same way work as intended.

```
Start-Process 'C:\Blah\install.exe' -Wait
```

The script is kicked off in an administrator instance of Powershell. I'm not sure if the installer doesn't like being kicked off by PS or if there is something more screwy going on.

What else can I try?

Comment: You don't need `Start-Process`. Just run the executable - type the name of the executable on PowerShell's command line and press `Enter`.

Comment: Right. I'm trying to run this automatically from the script. I have already tried running it with
    & C:\Blah\install.exe 
and the installer's behavior did not change.

Comment: If the installer spawns a separate executable, then all bets are off. PowerShell will wait for the first one to terminate, but it wouldn't know about any others.

Comment: Is the installer interactive? Does it require an input file to read answers?

Comment: Please describe `it does not run properly` what is (not) happening that is not intended?

Comment: I just found that just running the EXE from a admin PS prompt (no $ or Start-Process) outside of the script works as intended.

Comment: The `PATH` defined in `PS` may not have the correct directories to find `regedit.exe`. Running interactively uses the current session's `PATH`.

Comment: @alvits It's strange that it works for the other evault setup file in the script. How would I import the PATH so that the file knows where to look for regedit.exe?

Comment: Have you checked these 2 http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_env_path.htm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714877/setting-windows-powershell-path-variable?

Comment: The error message may be saying it can't find the .reg file. But in either case, if this error message is being generated by the installer, then you need to ask the author of the installer what the problem is.