# How do I set these paths in powershell?

Tags: powershell, path, classpath

Good Day

I am trying to set these paths in powershell but have not been successful in this regard. I have a DOS script that was initially written to set these paths but now I need it set in powershell.

Primarily, these paths are still used in the script to parse information, so in the same breathe, should act as a variable as well. Please help if possible. I am aware that powershell has a **Set-Location** function but would it serve the purpose as described above. Here are the paths scripted in DOS below:

```
   set CLASSPATH=D:\NetExpress\Base\Bin\WIN64\mfcobol.jar;.;%CLASSPATH%
   set COBIDY=D:\NetExpress\Base\SOURCE
   set COBLINK64=D:\NetExpress\Base\Bin\Linker
   set COBREG_64_PARSED=True
   set INCLUDE=D:\NetExpress\Base\INCLUDE
   set LIB=D:\NetExpress\Base\Lib\WIN64
   set MFTRACE_LOGS=D:\NetExpress\Base\MFTRACE\Logs
   set SCHEMA_PATH=D:\NetExpress\Base\SCHEMA
   set TXBIN=D:\NetExpress\Base
   set TXDIR=D:\NetExpress\Base
   set PATH=D:\NetExpress\Base\Bin\Linker;D:\NetExpress\Base\Bin\WIN64;D:\NetExpress\Base\Bin;D:\NetExpress\PACKAGES\x64;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\
   set COBPATH64=D:\NetExpress\Base\Bin\WIN64
   set LD_LIBRARY_PATH=D:\NetExpress\Base\Bin\WIN64;%int%
   set COBDIR=D:\NetExpress\Base\Bin\WIN64;%int%;D:\NetExpress\MFSQL\SOURCE
   set COBDIR64=D:\NetExpress\Base\Bin\WIN64
   set COBPATH=%exe%
   set COBCPY=%int%\LIBRYATM;%int%\LIBRYBOR;%int%\LIBRYBRO;%int%\LIBRYCHG;%int%\LIBRYCTA;%int%\LIBRYDCS;%int%\LIBRYGEN;%int%\LIBRYEN;%int%\LIBRYINV;%int%\LIBRYMIS;%int%\LIBRYSPY;%int%\LIBRYSWI;%int%\LIBRYTRE;%int%\LIBRYUNX;%int%\LIBRYCNV;D:\NetExpress\Base\SOURCE
   set LogFile=%CD%\logfile.log
```

Assist if possible please...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting Windows PowerShell path variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714877/setting-windows-powershell-path-variable)

Comment: `$env:CLASSPATH = "D:\NetExpress\Base\Bin\WIN64\mfcobol.jar;.;$env:CLASSPATH"` and so on

Answer (score 4):

It's as Mathias R. Jessen has mentioned in the comments
You'll have to use the in-built powershell variable $env.
$env has all the environment variables already defined in your system and you can add to them using 
`$env::VariableName = Value`
Example would be something like
`$env:CLASSPATH = "D:\NetExpress\Base\Bin\WIN64\mfcobol.jar;.;" + $env:CLASSPATH`
If setting environment variable is your only goal then this should do it, if you are planning to use these scripts later in the same script file I'd suggest you use powershell variables instead.
Also check out this [Microsoft Page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730964.aspx) for more on Environment Variables and Powershell

Comment: What about something like below?:

Comment: {set PATH=D:\NetExpress\Base\Bin\Linker;D:\NetExpress\Base\Bin\WIN64;D:\NetExpress\Base\Bin;D:\NetExpress\PACKAGES\x64;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\}

Comment: set COBCPY=%int%\LIBRYATM;%int%\LIBRYBOR;%int%\LIBRYBRO;%int%\LIBRYCHG;%int%\LIBRYCTA;%int%\LIBRYDCS;%int%\LIBRYGEN;%int%\LIBRYEN;%int%\LIBRYINV;%int%\LIBRYMIS;%int%\LIBRYSPY;%int%\LIBRYSWI;%int%\LIBRYTRE;%int%\LIBRYUNX;%int%\LIBRYCNV;D:\NetExpress\Base\SOURCE

Comment: @23Stringer - The idea is reference the set paths later in the script so it can be identified to do specific functions based on a path. How would I declare these paths in an instance like that?

Comment: @Julio A. That's good in a batch file not in powershell.  To the best of my knowledge Powershell has no 'set' command/command-let. Use `$CLASSPATH= "D:\NetExpress\Base\Bin\WIN64\mfcobol.jar;.;" + $env:CLASSPATH`. You can refer to them later using $CLASSPATH

Comment: @23Stringer - By referring to $CLASSPATH, all methods, classes and libraries used within the path?

Comment: @Julio A - I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean by 'all methods, classes and libraries within the path'. Are there files/scripts in these path that you want to access through script? If that's the case you can user `$CLASSPATH\ScriptName` or `$CLASSPATH\FileName` else I need some explanation.

Comment: PowerShell has both `environment variables` and `script variables`. Environment variables are referenced as from the PSProvider `Env:name`.  There is a separate set of script variables which are referenced by `$name`.

Comment: Use `Get-ChildItem Env:` and `Get-ChildItem Variable:` to see the two different lists.