# Winrm script not executing via Jenkins

Tags: windows, powershell, jenkins

I have a winrm script and I am using Jenkins to execute this script from windows slave to remote machine and I have copied psexec.exe, pservice.exe in windows slaves c:\windows\system32 folder. But when I execute the below script from jenkins it gives an error that

> PsExec.exe : The term 'PsExec.exe' is not recognized as the name of a
>   cmdlet, function, script file, or operable  program. Check the
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
>   is correct and try again. At
>   C:\Users\cicd\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson5218849623344511653.ps1:66
>   char:7
>   +       PsExec.exe \$computer -accepteula -s C:\Windows\System32\winrm.cmd qc -qu ...
>   +       ~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (PsExec.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException**

Code:

```
foreach ($computer in $hosts) {
$result = winrm id -r:$computer 2> $null
    if ($lastExitCode -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "WinRM already enabled on" $computer "..." -ForegroundColor green
    } else {
    Write-Host "Enabling WinRM on" $computer "..." -ForegroundColor red 
     PsExec.exe \\$computer -accepteula -s C:\Windows\System32\winrm.cmd qc -quiet 

    if ($LastExitCode -eq 0) {
        PsService.exe \\$computer -accepteula restart WinRM 
        $result  = winrm id -r:$computer 2>$null

    if ($LastExitCode -eq 0) {Write-Host "WinRM successfully enabled!" -ForegroundColor green}
        else {Write-Host "WinRM not enabled!" -ForegroundColor red}

       } 

    }  
}
```

When I execute the script from windows slaves powershell window it works fine. but from jenkins it gives the error.

Does anyone have any idea why am I getting that error ?

Answer (score 1):

The error is stating that it can't find `PsExec.exe`

in the error you can see that it's mentioning `AppData\Local\Temp\-.ps1`, this means that the script is being launched from the temporary folder, rather than wherever you actually have PsExec stored, the easiest ways to resolve this are to either:

- add the full path for PsExec to your `$Path` variable. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714877/setting-windows-powershell-path-variable)

this will ensure it is automatically resolved, or

- Reference the executable by its full name

i.e. replace `PsExec.exe` in your code with the full version `C:\Path\To\File\PsExec.exe`

Comment: I tried above methord. As the psexec file already there in system32 folder it takes even though  am running it from different directory.

Comment: I tried above methord. As the psexec file already there in system32 folder it takes even though  am running it from different directory.But script still gives error.But when I run the script from slave machine it runs without any issue

Comment: @Shimith have you tried it using the full name of the executable in the script?

Comment: Yes, I have tried in below format.But still same issue                                               C:\Windows\System32\PsExec.exe \\$computer -accepteula -s winrm.cmd qc -quiet

Comment: at the top of your code try put in `Get-Item "C:\Windows\System32\PsExec.exe" and see if that also fails, if that also fails it means the script is either being blocked from viewing it, or executing in a context where it can't see it for another reason.

Comment: yes, even now it fails.But I can execute the script locally from that windows slave machine without any issue