# Variable path PowerShell - Win10

Tags: powershell, ssh, windows-10

I've downloaded "[openSSH-Win64](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases/)", so I can ssh into a Linux server using my PowerShell.

It works if I go into the folder and call the `ssh.exe`.
I don't wanna go into the folder every time I need to use SSH.

I've tried [this tutorial](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10) but it doesn't work. When typing `ssh` on powershell I get this error:

```
ComSpec : The term 'ComSpec' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

**QUESTION:**

How can I create a variable path or something so every time I type `ssh` into my PowerShell it will automatically call this executable file `C:\Users\druml\Downloads\OpenSSH-Win64\OpenSSH-Win64\ssh.exe`?

**UPDATE:**

I was able to get this working on the Command Line (cmd), not using PowerShell. In my case I really need to use PowerShell.

Comment: You're probably looking for a way to set an environment path in Windows. Just saw you're using Win10. Here you go, check this on how to set the environment variable: https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10

Comment: @flen do I need to restart my Windows? it didn't work!

Comment: I don't remember... If you can, I think it's worth a try. But are you sure you included the path correctly?

Comment: take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714877/setting-windows-powershell-path-variable

Comment: You don't have to reboot your pc, you just need to reopen powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this by following: https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10

Once you have added the new Variable, make sure to restart PowerShell as `@J. Bergmann` has mentioned.