# Minikube on Windows behind an HTTP Proxy

Tags: windows, docker, kubernetes, proxy, minikube

I'm trying to learn Kubernetes, so I tried Minikube v1.2 on Windows (10, 64-bit). The problem is I'm behind an HTTP Proxy. The Proxy is already set up in Windows, I always log in when I open up a Firefox session.

I followed the instruction in https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/http_proxy.md setting up the 3 env variables (HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY and NO_PROXY). I found out, thanks to another issue, that I had to set HTTPS_PROXY equal as HTTP_PROXY (I think because of the proxy itself somehow).

I launch this command to create the minikube VM:

```sh
minikube start --profile kubes --docker-env http_proxy="%HTTP_PROXY%"
--docker-env https_proxy="%HTTPS_PROXY%" --docker-env no_proxy="%NO_PROXY%"
```

Anyway I'm trying to do the minikube quickstart tutorial with the hello-minikube but I'm not able to reach the service. I always got error 504.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I did it.

I had to add the `minikube ip` returned address to the NO_PROXY variable.
The problem is that everytime I delete and recreate the VM for some reason, I have to change the ENV variable.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: As mentioned above please set-up [env variables for windows](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/http_proxy.md#windows).   As per documentation: `As of v1.0, minikube automatically configures the Docker instance inside of the VM to use the proxy environment variables, unless you have specified a --docker-env override` so you should'nt change those parameters during startup.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation:

[Using Minikube with an HTTP Proxy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/minikube/#using-minikube-with-an-http-proxy)

> If your Virtual Machine address is 192.168.99.100, then chances are your proxy settings will prevent kubectl from directly reaching it. To by-pass proxy configuration for this IP address, you should modify your no_proxy settings. You can do so with:

```
export no_proxy=$no_proxy,$(minikube ip)
```

In windows you should consider adding these to your [system settings or using setx](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/http_proxy.md#windows).

Please follow refer to [Setting Windows PowerShell environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714877/setting-windows-powershell-environment-variables)

Hope this help.