# cant run pipenv install django==2.1 in powershell(cmd either), why?

Tags: django, powershell, cmd, terminal, pycharm

As you can see the terminal in pycharm easily lays the foundation for creating a django project.

[image: as you can see it's making it in pycharm terminal]

but in powershell(cmd either) I see this....

[image: They give me an error]

**so how should i run the command to make it work in powershell or cmd either ?**

**is there any other way to make me able (not to be confined in pycharm terminal) to do the same with powershell and cmd ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is your python path is not in the MS terminal that you got the pipenv error. To see that behaviour in your pycharm, type:
    `#which python`

The pycharm screen should show full path for your python in pycharm.

To fix the problem in your powershell terminal, you must add the full path for your python to your environment of that terminal. If you want to use the same python path as in your pycharm, you can add the python path from the pycharm 'which python' output to your powershell - For powershell path, See [Setting Windows PowerShell environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714877/setting-windows-powershell-environment-variables)

Comment: i did it.. but it shows me this error `'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: I found the way, i should have installed pipenv by `pip install pipenv` in powershell, cmd either to then be able to do the same with powershell and cmd. Now i tried it and it worked , thank you .

Comment: I don't have Windows to verify on your 'which' problem, but you can open "Python console" in pycharm to check for your python path (i.e. it may show full path to your python at the beginning of your 'python console' in pycharm - mine does that.)