# node-tesseract-ocr 'tesseract' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, ocr, tesseract

So I am working on an app that can read text on image files, I considered using tesseract.js but it is extremely slow. I read where someone was saying that node-tesseract-ocr is a bit fast. Though it requires installing tesseract-OCR, which I did successfully and can be accessed via the command-line. I also installed node-tesseract-ocr package and on testing, I get this error:

```
'tesseract' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How can I solve this ? Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Add tesseract.exe folder path to your Environmental Variables for your PC.

Comment: That doesn't work. I had done that before if you read the description

Comment: Sorry to hear that, are you using Visual Studio Code? If so change the default terminal from Powershell to CMD. Source currently open issue with the developer https://github.com/zapolnoch/node-tesseract-ocr/issues/6

Answer (score 0):

It unfortunately looks like CMD and Powershell have different environmental variables to set the path of. Following: [Setting Windows PowerShell environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714877/setting-windows-powershell-environment-variables):

Have you tried executing `$env:Path += ";<tesseractPath>"` to add the tesseract path of Powershell?