# PowerShell: Add every sub-directory to path

Tags: powershell, path, appveyor

On Windows 10 and via PowerShell, how do you add every sub-directory to the PATH variable?

I fine some method for Linux (e.g., [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17715/how-can-i-set-all-subdirectories-of-a-directory-into-path)), and "adapting" them to PowerShell, I came across the following.

```
'$env:PATH = $env:PATH + (find C:\Users\appveyor\ -type d -printf "\";%pbuild\\"")'
```

This throws `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

A bit more context: I am running this on appveyor, and trying to add every path under `appveyor` (simplified for clarity) such as `C:\Users\appveyor\*\build\` to path.

Comment: That has been answered before. You could have searched before you asked. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714877/setting-windows-powershell-environment-variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714877/setting-windows-powershell-environment-variables)  ... take look at the answer of hoge

Comment: But this is a different question; this is not about setting the env PATH, it is rather about using `FIND` properly in concert with setting the PATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$env:PATH = 
    @($env:PATH) + 
    [string]::join(
        ";", 
        (Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "[PATH TO SEARCH]" -Directory -Recurse).fullname
    )
```

This based on @briantist's suggestion; the main difference is in the `join` syntax.

To get this work on appveyor, do the following:

```
{ps:
    "$env:PATH = 
         @($env:PATH) + [string]::join(
             \";\", 
             (Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath \"[PATH TO SEARCH]\" -Directory -Recurse).fullname
    )"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `find` command on Linux is very different from the `Find` command on Windows.

In your case, I would use `Get-ChildItem` in PowerShell (which can also be used via the aliases `gci`, `dir`, `ls`), to return an array of directory objects, added to the current path casted as an array, and then `-join` them with the Windows path separator, which is a semicolon `;`.

That might look like this:

```bsh
$env:PATH = (
    @($env:PATH) + (
        Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'C:\Users\appveyor' -Directory -Recurse
    )
) -join [System.IO.Path]::PathSeparator # <- that could just be a literal string ';'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; however, I still get the `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.` error.