# How to run powershell script in anaconda prompt?

Tags: python, powershell, path, anaconda

I am using a windows pc with no admin rights. Python is installed but only works in anaconda prompt and not in normal cmd prompt because it is not added to path. Since I have no admin rights I cannot add it.

I have a fairly simple powershell script that runs a bunch of python scripts:

```
cd mydir
python script1
"script 1 done"
python script2
"finished"
```

EDIT: Right now, I open anaconda prompt and manually paste the script in and hit enter. Everything works perfect. Is there a way to do that in powershell, i.e. tell powershell to open anaconda prompt (not standard cmd) and paste the script to
it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding !all three! paths fixed the problem for me.

```
$env:path += ';C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\' 
$env:path += ';C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\'
$env:path += ';C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add it to your path yourself, either in powershell:

```
$env:path += ';C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3'

cd mydir
python script1
"script 1 done"
python script2
"finished"
```

Or in your windows profile.  Either in the Control Panel, or see the "User" form of this: [Setting Windows PowerShell environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714877/setting-windows-powershell-environment-variables/2571200#2571200)

The shortcut to Anaconda powershell does a lot of things.  Somehow you have to reproduce this if you don't want to use it.  I'm not an Anaconda user.

```
%windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -Command "& 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1' ; conda activate 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3' "
```

Maybe put this at the top of your script.  It would modify the path as well.

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1
conda activate C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
```

Comment: I still get python not found error. When I manually try to login into I need admin rights. Running the commands in your link also returns that I need higher privilege to modify the path variables.

Comment: What is the location of python.exe?

Comment: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe

Comment: And setting $env:path to that at the top of your script doesn't work?

Comment: if i run $env:path += ';C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' python -- version I get the python not found error

Comment: Sorry, just put the directory.  I edited my answer.

Comment: yep - that works thanks! But when running my script now it throws import errors for numpy and pandas. Both work fine in anaconda prompt