# How do I create persistent path variables?

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, path-variables

I've found that the `$HOME` variable can be rather useful for keyboard-only navigation in PowerShell. It would be nice to have a number of shortcuts stored as persistent path variables that can be accessed using the same syntax. I've seen the method `$env:MyTestVariable = "My temporary test variable."` but the result isn't persistent and still has to be accessed by typing `$env:MyTestVariable` which is not as succinct as the desired `$MyTestVariable`.

How can I create such variables and control what level has access to them (aka *User*, *Machine*, and *Process*)?

Comment: You can define those variables in your profiles. Either in AllUsersAllHosts, AllUsersCurrentHost, CurrentUserAllHosts or CurrentUserCurrentHost.  ;-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2571200/5298150

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting Windows PowerShell environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714877/setting-windows-powershell-environment-variables)

Comment: That question asks about "setting" enviroment variables which may, or may not, be identical to the procedure of creating *new* ones. Additionally, it doesn't explicitly address the specifics of my post regarding the verbosity of $env:MyTestVariable as opposed to $MyTestVariable. In short-- while it may be possible to deduce the answer to my question from that post it is not identical.