# cockroach DB issue to start : Fail to initialize the node: unable to load named timezone

Tags: windows, powershell, timezone, cockroachdb, zoneinfo

cockroach DB issue to start : Fail to initialize the node: unable to load named timezone.

I downloaded the zoneinfo.zip and unziped and configured the environment variable ZONEINFO and given into the path like C:\Program Files\timezone\zoneinfo but still facing the same. screenshot attached.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I89vf.png)

Comment: Please [don't use images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors), put the text directly in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the latest beta version on Windows. It's a good idea to read the installation instructions when doing this.

The [install page for 20.2.0-beta2 on Windows](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/dev/install-cockroachdb-windows.html#download-the-executable) has a section detailing how to setup the timezone database on Windows.

Quoting:

> To ensure that CockroachDB can use location-based names as time zone
> identifiers, download Go's official [zoneinfo.zip](https://github.com/golang/go/raw/master/lib/time/zoneinfo.zip) and set the ZONEINFO
> environment variable to point to the zip file.

Make sure of two things:

- set the environment variable **in the same powershell session** as the one in which you are running Cockroach
- the environment variable **should point to the zip file**, not the extracted contents.

You can also make it permanent, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/714918/4966953) for how to do so.