# env-path not persisted with Powershell

Tags: powershell

According to [Setting Windows PowerShell environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714877/setting-windows-powershell-environment-variables) it is possible to modify environment path in Powershell with

```
$env:Path = "C:\jdk-16.0.1\bin" + ';' + $env:Path
```

I tried (with admin rights) and checked $env:Path : it's ok

But if I close and reopen powershell, it's gone so did I miss something ?

Comment: Use `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()` to persist env vars, as detailed by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2571200/7571258).

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to set an environment variable only for PowerShell, but not all other processes, add `$env:Path = ...` to your `$Profile` file. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/714918/7571258