# [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable doesn't set permanetly

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

From [Setting Windows PowerShell environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2571200/3416774), I use this as admin:

```
PS D:\>[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $env:Path + ";C:\bin", "Machine")
```

I restart the shell and check if it works:

```
PS D:\> $env:path.contains("C:\bin")
False
```

Why is that?

Comment: Did you check it manually by simply outputting the whole environment variable `$env:path`?

Comment: yes. It doesn't there. Plus that shouldn't the `$env:path.contains("C:\bin")` be suffice?

Comment: You have to run this as administrator. You know that, don't you? Try `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $env:Path + "C:\bin", "Machine")` ... without the semikolon. At least that works on my machine. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Yes I ran it as admin. Without the semicolon it still doesn't work. I don't think removing it has any impact on here

Comment: It might be some issue in your environment though. As I said - it works as intended on my machine.

Comment: yes, but how do I identify that problem?

Comment: I'd start with a reboot. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The [System.SetEnvironmentVariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable?view=net-7.0) call manipulates the system registry key that holds the persisted environment. A call using GetEnvironmentVariable with the same parameters should show that it has been set in the persisted registry. However, your check is to launch a new process. New processes inherit their environment from the parent process which in the case of launching a command prompt from the desktop is Explorer. Explorer needs to be told the environment has changed. The system dialog that changes the environment broadcasts a [WM_SETTINGCHANGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-settingchange) message to do this. Then Explorer re-reads the persisted registry key and new processes will start with the new environment variable values.

You may need to broadcast a WM_SETTINGCHANGE message to notify processes of the change. When I try your example in PowerShell however (as Administrator) it does work. So the broadcast window message should be being done for you already.

Comment: Example: this is how you [send WM_SETTINGCHANGE from a PowerShell script](https://gist.github.com/0xfeeddeadbeef/2c03971709f457bd726cea20c52f94d7)